# DataTables - datepicker conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5, twitter-bootstrap-3

First of all I'm less than beginner on dev.
I'm using Laravel 5.4, in master template I have the following scripts inclusions:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="js\DataTables-1.10.15\DataTables.js"></script>
<script src="js\bootstrap-dropdownhover.min.js"></script>
<script src="js\scripts.js"></script>
<script src="js\SweetAlert\sweetalert.min.js"></script>
In html view:
<form>
....
 <input  id="dataFabricatiei" name="dataFabricatiei" type="date"/>
....
</form>
```

In scripts.js

```
$('#dataFabricatiei').datepicker();
```

I get this error in browser console and DataTables don't work anymore:

```
scripts.js:28 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (scripts.js:28)
    at fire (DataTables.js:3244)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (DataTables.js:3374)
    at Function.ready (DataTables.js:3594)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (DataTables.js:3629)
(anonymous) @ scripts.js:28
fire @ DataTables.js:3244
fireWith @ DataTables.js:3374
ready @ DataTables.js:3594
completed @ DataTables.js:3629
```

If I remove the line

```
$('#dataFabricatiei').datepicker();
```

than DataTables work but no more datepicker

Thank you for your time,

Radu Cruceana
:)

Comment: Try `jQuery(#...).datePicker`

Comment: can you show us your scripts.js around line 28?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you sir,
I think I've got it!
DataTables script should be included BEFORE Bootstrap date-picker
For me the correct order is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js\DataTables-1.10.15\DataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="js\bootstrap-dropdownhover.min.js"></script>
<script src="js\scripts.js"></script>
<script src="js\SweetAlert\sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

But I still don't know why is it like that :)

Answer (score 1):

I did this which works.
However, Could you post the contents of the script file, probably that might help in debugging

```
<html>
<head></head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#dataFabricatiei').datepicker();
</script>
<body>
 <input  id="dataFabricatiei" name="dataFabricatiei" type="date"/>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L631vreo/1/

Comment: Thank you sire but actually is not working,  in this way is acting like a normal date input without bootstrap datepicker extension.